# Prestashop - Delete Admin Options

Tags: prestashop

Is there a way in Prestashop to delete the options in the backend to leave the admin with just changing products, currency etc. but not the modules, themes, or anything that changes the site?

Answer (score 6):

You don't have to delete the menus, you can manage administrator permissions.

Simply create a new administrator profile in `Administration` -> `Profiles`, set permissions in `Administration` -> `Permissions` and set the profile for the administrator in `Administration` -> `Employees`.